# Python script writes gibberish to file

Tags: python, sockets, udp, syslog

Here's a script I am using to receive syslog and append it to a text file:

```
# Receives packets on udp port 514 and
# writes to syslog.txt

from socket import *

# Set the socket parameters
host = "myhost"
port = 514
buf = 1024
addr = (host,port)

# Create socket and bind to address
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)

# Receive messages
while 1:
    data,addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    if not data:
        print "Client has exited!"
        break
    else:
        print "\nReceived message '", data,"'"

        # This will create a new file or overwrite an existing file.
        with open("C:\syslog.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(str(data))

# Close socket
UDPSock.close()
```

Scripts works fine and text is appended to file. I see it and it's read well. However, the moment I close python, that txt file data is translated to gibberish text. Any ideas why? Am I supposed to do something else before appended socket data to a file?

Thanks.

Comment: what text editor are you viewing the file in?

Comment: I am viewing it in notepad. Here is what I get: ㄼ㈷䄾杵㈠‹㐱㐺㨹㐱匠㕁〴嬠䥆䕒䅗䱌孝䥆䕒䅗䱌⁝晛物睥污嵬䰠䝏偟䍁䕋孔剄偏⁝䤠㵎䅌⁎传呕匽䱅⁆剓㵃㤱⸲㘱⸸㠴㈮㘱䐠呓㈽㔵㈮㔵㈮㔵㈮㔵倠佒佔唽偄匠呐ㄽ㔷〰䐠呐ㄽ㔷‌​〰㰀㜱㸲畁⁧㤲ㄠ㨴ㄵ㌺‹䅓㐵‰䙛剉坅䱁嵌䙛剉坅䱁嵌嬠楦敲慷汬⁝

Comment: Try without `str()` around `data`. i.e., print >> myfile, data

Answer (score 4):

You're not parsing the syslog packets.  Syslog [is a protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424); it's not just plain text.  Data characters are most likely ending up in your file, which may be tripping some automatic character detection.

Comment: I thought str(data) was converting packet data to string. If that's not the case, then how should I implement this? I am new to python.

Comment: `data` is already a string of bytes received from the socket; `str` will not convert it further, nor is it reasonable to expect it to know how to disassemble syslog packets.  You will have to either implement syslog packet disassembly in your code or find a library like the one suggested in this answer to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12186092/722332

Answer (score 1):

This might straight do what you want to achieve (parsing the syslog protocol and dump it): 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/loggerglue/0.9

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggesting doing open("C:\syslog.txt", "at") instead of open("C:\syslog.txt", "a"), but re-reading the python dox, text is the default (unlike with C, where my memory says that binary is the default which leads to issues when running on windows).

My other suggestion would be to put a plain text header at the top of the file when you first create it; not sure what you're using to read the file after, but Notepad and Wordpad use some heuristics to figure out what UTF-8 or other encoding is being used, and I've definitely seen cases where this fails badly.  (Search wordpad BOM guess)

Comment: I am thinking about using codecs to decode it. For that I need to find out cisco syslog encoding format. I'll be back with my research :)